# How to properly validate JSON request in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

As the title says. How can I validate JSON request in symfony?

I found this [package](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) for validating JSON but it doesn't work with request object.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use JsonSchema\Validator;


class ApiController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/api/store-data", name="store-data", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function storeDashboardLayout(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $validator = new Validator();
        $validation = $validator->validate(
            $request,
            (object)[
                "type" => "object",
                "properties" => (object)[
                    "new_layout" => (object)[
                        "type"=> "string"
                    ]
                ],
                "required" => [
                    "new_layout"
            ]
        ]);

        if(!$validator->isValid()){
            // json is not valid do something
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I send a POST request to that endpoint with correct value (`{"new_layout": "blabla"}`) it ends up in if clause - not valid.

What is a good approach to achieve that? Doesn't exist something like I could define how my incoming JSON would look like in comment section?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but that is only for forms. And it requires to create object for every endpoint. It seems to be more complicated for me. Let's say I have 100 API endpoints I don't wanna create 100 new classes just for that.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, "_properly validate request_" and "_How can I validate POST parameters_" led me to think you talked about forms. But you want a JSON validator I guess.

Comment: The `validate()` method always returns an instance of `ConstraintViolationListInterface`. This means that your `!$validation` check will always evaluate to `true`. You need to test whether the list contains any violation (note that the default implementation `ConstraintViolationList` provided by the Validator component implements `Countable` so you can just use `count()` here for example).

Comment: @xabbuh Thank you. Unfortunately, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution what I've found so far is to convert JSON request to associated array manually and then verify:

```
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $validator = new Validator();
    $validation = $validator->validate(
        $data,
        (object)[
            "type" => "array",
            "properties" => (object)[
                "new_layout" => (object)[
                    "type"=> "string"
                ]
            ],
            "required" => [
                "new_layout"
        ]
    ]);
```

The only thing that needs to be done:
Every `"type" => "object"` must be renamed to `"type" => "array"`